# retreving computer names over network

Tags: batch-file, shutdown

I can shutdown other computers on the network using the following command.

```
shutdown -i
```

Is it then possible to also collect a list of all computer names on that network...?

...Preferably with user names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use 'net view' to enumerate all the machines.

Comment: That was my first try then all i got was my own pc name and i thought what the heck ill execute a shutdown on a colleguse computer wich worked (he hit the roof) but net view isnt giving me names

Comment: I was able to remotly shutdown his pc which leads me to think so

Comment: That's not the same thing.. sending RPC commands doesn't require the same rights..